# crystal reports are not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

[image]I am using Crystal reports 13.0 with Visual studio 2010.Crystal reports are not showing up in screen .Its not displaying any error in Event logs also.How can we overcome this problem.

Comment: Inadequate information provided.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data source connection setup?Need a bit more info as it could be number of things also dependent on application type.

Desktop application?
Is the data source connection setup?
Another issue - is the client runtime installed?

Web application?
what browser are you using?
Cr13 will not work in IE 11 try compatibility mode
If a web application you will need the .net cryatalreports folder in te root of your website

Hope that helps

Comment: We have used in WebApplication and we are using IE9.We have tried in compatible mode but in vain.We have copied Aspnet_client folder to website path and it was worked.This is not suitable to copy the folder in all website folders.Is there any other alternate solution.?